# Build complex MySQL Query with several Joins

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following tables:

**disciplines**

```sql
id             int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT
name           var_char(50)
speciality     int(11)  -- The ID of the speciality
```

**grades**

```sql
id             int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT
student_id     int(11)  -- the ID of the student from `students` table
discipline_id  int(11)  -- the ID of the discipline from `disciplines` table
grade          int(2)
```

Let's say I have two variables: one holding the ID of the student and the other one holding the ID of the speciality.
What I need to do is to create a query that returns as a result a table with two columns: `discipline` and `grade`. The `discipline` column should have every discipline that will be studied in the given speciality and the `grade` column should show the grade for that discipline for that student (from the given variable).
The rules:
 - The student may have more than one grade for one discipline (as multiple rows in the **grades** table)
 - The student may not have any grades for one discipline. In that case the `grades` column in the result should show `NULL` as result

Example result:

```sql
discipline   |      grade
-------------|------------
Math         |         2
Math         |         2
Math         |         3
Programming  |         4
DB Basics    |      NULL
and so on... |  
-------------------------
```

Is it possible to do that with one query?

**Edit:**
I tried to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT disciplines.name, grades.grade
FROM disciplines
INNER JOIN grades ON grades.discipline_id = disciplines.id
WHERE disciplines.speciality = 3 AND grades.student_id = 97
```

The problem here is I do not have the other disciplines from the same speciality, the ones that this student hasn't any grades yet.

Comment: 1 query is possible, more queries can be faster... Wht have you tried so far and what was the query time?

Comment: I dont see a request for help with an issue, all I see is a specificaltion. **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort on your behalf to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being asked. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: In my case the time is not that important. I have tried some queries so far, the best I get is every grades that the has but not showing the disciplines that he hasn't any grades yet

Comment: Excuse me, I missed to add what I have tried so far. I just edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` so that it shows `NULL` in the disciplines that do not have a grade yet, and place the condition on the student ID there so it doesn't restrict to only rows with a value:

```
SELECT disciplines.name, grades.grade
FROM disciplines
LEFT JOIN grades ON grades.discipline_id = disciplines.id AND grades.student_id = 97
WHERE disciplines.speciality = 3
```

Comment: This actually solves my problem. I did not know that a condition can be set inside the JOIN. Thank you, not only for the solution, I learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select disciplines.name as discipline ,grades.grade 
from grades 
    join disciplines on grades.discipline_id = disciplines.id 
where grade.student_id='123' 
and disciplines.speciality = '234';
```

didn't have to try it, so hope it's correct :P

Comment: This is what I tried. As I said after editing my post, the problem I am facing here is that the result I am getting does not contain the disciplines that the student hasn't any grades yet.

Comment: i might have a stupid question, but do you have a db record, that has a discipline name and no value in the grade column?